# self.draw.draw_polygon(xy, fill, 1) TypeError: coordinate list must contain at least 2 coordinates

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
def polygon(self, xy, fill=None, outline=None):
    """Draw a polygon."""
    ink, fill = self._getink(outline, fill)
    if fill is not None:
        self.draw.draw_polygon(xy, fill, 1)
    if ink is not None and ink != fill:
        self.draw.draw_polygon(xy, ink, 0)
```

But I'm getting this Error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Abir Khan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 241, in polygon
    self.draw.draw_polygon(xy, fill, 1)
TypeError: coordinate list must contain at least 2 coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your xy coordinate values and their shape this Error is due to it only.

xy should be like this:

```
 [(180.0, 60.0), (153.63961030678928, 102.42640687119285), (90.0, 120.0), (26.360389693210728, 102.42640687119285), (0.0, 60.000000000000014), (26.36038969321071, 17.573593128807154), (89.99999999999999, 0.0), (153.63961030678928, 17.57359312880714)]
```

Refer to this Blog: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagedraw-draw-polygon-method/

Comment: eactly can you tell me what changes should I make in code

Answer (score 0):

`draw_polygon` should takes a sequence of points. In other words, `xy` should be a list of tuples containing x and y values for each point.

```
points = [(1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 0), (3, 0)]
self.draw.draw_polygon(points, ink, 0)
```

read the docs [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html?highlight=draw%20polygon#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon)

Comment: eactly can you tell me what changes should I make in code

Comment: pass xy as a list of tuples containing x and y values for each point